# Does a voltage divider circuit have to end up at ground?

Tags: voltage, ground, voltage-divider

I am learning about voltage divider circuits and how they work. Here's an image as example:

[image: simple voltage divider]

After the voltage from V<sub>in</sub> goes through two resistors, after the second resistor, does it have to end up at ground (aka the 0 V point)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not have to end up at 0V.

It can end up being connected to any voltage required to perform the operation you need, such as dividing +/-  5V input range to a single-ended ADC with 0 to 5V range.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage does not **go in** or **through**. Voltage is applied **across** an element or collection of elements. Current travels **through** elements.

The diagram below shows two circuits: One without a ground symbol, and another with a ground symbol.

The voltages \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$ are assumed to be with reference to ground. On the left, The voltage \$Vac\$ uses double-subscript notation to specify the nodes that the voltage is measured between. Comparing the two diagrams \$Vin = Vab\$ and \$Vout = Vac\$

\$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$ use single subscript notation to indicate that the voltage is referred to ground.

Ground should be considered a reference for measurement and/or a connection to local earth. It really has no effect on circuit analysis except to establish a 0 volt reference.

If there are several ground symbols on a diagram, they serve to show that the points are electrically connected together and to be considered 0 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwjjNB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No, Ground basically considered as reference voltage, from which we can say that, the range of Vout will be in between 0 to Vin. If we connect voltage (Vo) in place of ground, the range of Vout will change from Vo to Vin (w.r.t ground).
Just like a Potentiometer.